# How to share a common subexpression in an UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider this (contrived) query:

```
UPDATE table1
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON ...
  SET
    table1.a = table1.x + table2.y,
    table1.b = table1.a * 2;
```

It updates `table1` based on the correlated data from `table2`. Note that `table1.b` is supposed to be updated using the (just computed) value of `table1.a`.

According to the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html),

> Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order.

In my tests, the columns were not updated in the order I need, perhaps because MySQL thinks this is a multiple-table update (although just one table gets actually updated).

I also tried using a user-defined variable to store the result like this:

```
UPDATE table1
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON ...
  SET
    table1.a = @sum,
    table1.b = @sum * 2
  WHERE
    @sum := table1.x + table2.y;
```

That didn't work either (the fields weren't updated from their NULL values). And again, the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) say this isn't supported.

I am also aware that I can create a stored function to compute the subexpression, but for several reasons it doesn't seem to be worth the effort.

So, is there some other way to share the subexpression between the assignments? The goal of sharing is both to prevent recomputation and to avoid the duplication in the source code, although more of the latter than the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to join a subquery, presuming `table1` has a primary key constraint on `id` -

```
update table1
join (
  select table1.id, table1.x + table2.y as xy
  from table1
  left join table2 on ...
) as base
  on (base.id = table1.id)
set table1.a = base.xy,
    table1.b = base.xy * 2;
```

Although, if this bothers you, you can probably exploit variable assignment -

```
update table1
left join table2 on ...
set table1.a = (@sum := table1.x + table2.y),
    table1.b = @sum * 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should have worked:

```
UPDATE table1
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON ...
  SET
    table1.a = table1.x + table2.y,
    table1.b = (table1.x + table2.y) * 2;
```

Comment: Of course this would work, but the question is specifically about *sharing* the subexpression, not duplicating it. I explain the motivation behind sharing towards the end of the post. Granted, in my real use case, the expression is much more complex than mere `table1.x + table2.y`; as I said, this is only a simplified example.

Comment: In such a case you must be able to do the evaluation of `table1.x + table2.y` within the `LEFT JOIN` like this: `UPDATE table1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT (table1.x + table2.y) as a_val, ... FROM table1 JOIN table2 WHERE ...) AS tab2 SET table1.a = tab2.a_val, table1.b = tab2.a_val * 2;`

Comment: This is a subquery, right? Will it have performance implications?

Comment: @SameerMirji - I don't think you can refer to `table1` from within that subquery.  I get `Unknown column 'table1.x' in 'field list'`

Comment: @pyrospade: If you see carefully, the subquery's `FROM` clause has `table1` in it ;)

Comment: Thanks Sameer, I ended up accepting pyrospade's answer since I couldn't accept a comment, but I think your answers are more or less the same.